# Continous barcode scanning with zxing

Tags: android, zxing

I am creating barcode scanning app in which I want to scan barcode continuously like attached image.

I tried using this link https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java but I got confused how to stop `decodeContinuous(callback)`.

If I used `decodeSingle(callback)`, it won't allow me to scan next barcode.
I need a result like attached image.I am new to android and need help.

[image]
 There will be Data logger, Tyre and Sensors.First, I have to scan Data logger barcode and then barcode of sensor and Tyre and want to show result in table format

Answer (score 0):

Just use `barcodeView.pause()`.